# Differentiation under the integral sign? $\int_0^1 (x\ln(x))^{50} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 (x\ln(x))^{50}\,dx$$

This was listed as a question using Differentiation Under the Integral Sign.  How do I solve this?

First, I tried introducing a parameter $p$.

$$I(p)=\int_0^1 (x\ln(x))^{p}\,dx$$
Then, I differentiated it with respect to $p$. It became messy real quick.
$$I'(p)=\int_0^1 (x\ln(x))^{p}\ln(x\ln(x))\,dx$$
There's no way to integrate this (easily).

Then, I tried putting $t$ elsewhere, then using $$u=\frac{x}{p}$$

$$I(p)=\int_0^p (x\ln(x))^{50}\,dx$$
$$I(p)=p\int_0^1 (up\ln(up))^{50}\,du$$
When I differentiate it with respect to $p$ (using the product rule), it becomes a mess and difficult to integrate.

How do you solve this, and what's your thought process when you see an integral like this?
(I am aware that it is possible to use integration by parts 50 times but that's messy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\partial_kx^k=\partial_k\exp(k\ln x)=x^k\ln x$. Differentiating $\int_0^1x^kdx=\frac{1}{k+1}$ some $n$ times with respect to $k$ 
 gives $\int_0^1x^k\ln^nxdx=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(k+1)^{n+1}}$. So the result is $\frac{50!}{51^{51}}$.

Comment: I can't follow past 1/k+1 :(

Comment: @helpme Does my edit help?

Comment: Thanks I got it :p So basically, instead of starting from the integral, it is possible to start from a simpler integral and try to make it look like the integral to solve